# Newbie needs help with Clothes simulation

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, physics, cloth-simulation, properties

I simulated a sleeveless shirt that I made for my character but for some reason when I hit the play button it separates in half as if it gets ripped off

I'm so confused cuz I didn't pressed anything wrong and didn't miss anything...

Does anyone know why this happens? Any solutions to fix this problem?

[image: Shirt separates]

Comment: Do you have a mirror modifier on the shirt?

Comment: Yes!! the mirror modifier is on.... I have no idea why this is happening  @Blunder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the answer after having a look at your [blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/cb2560158d1046e297598a46ceecc021).

As suspected, the problem is the *Mirror* modifier and that the center vertices are not merged but overlap. In fact, the complete faces overlap.

[image: content of blend file]
<sup>A fews things need to be fixed</sup>

There are a few more problems you should fix:

- all objects in the scene are rotated 90 degrees to the left. So you should rotate them -90 degrees around the Z-axis to get everything right again.
   Because of the rotation, the front view (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>) shows the right side and the left side view (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>) shows the objects from the front. Furthermore, with *Mirror* you have to mirror everything on the Y-axis to mirror the sides. With the shirt, it still works via the X-axis because it is rotated again. It is confusing.
  In *Object* mode press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, then <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to rotate it.
- I've activated *Face Orientation* in the *Overlays* menu (the icon in the top middle of the screenshot). As you can see the front of the shirt is red. That is, half is turned inside out and will cause shading issues. You can flip the faces in the *Edit* mode, when you select the front part of the shirt and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, *Flip*.
- having selected the front part of the shirt, disable the *Clipping* box of the *Mirror* modifier just for now. Then you can move the shirt a bit to the left (character's point of view, to the right from the screen's POV) to drag the shirt apart. Enable *Clipping* again and move the part back to close the gap.
- repeat the steps for the back of the shirt
- the head's mesh has duplicated vertices. You can remove them in *Edit* mode with <kbd>M</kbd>, *Merge by Distance*

[image: fixed things]
<sup>Things are fixed now (rotated, flipped, removed overlapping faces)</sup>

Finally, run the simulation. It should work fine now:
[image: the sewn shirt]
<sup>Sewn shirt, created by the cloth simulation</sup>

For optimization, you can scale the top of the shirt a little along the X-axis before the simulation to make it tighter at the top and fit better.

There can be a gap at the sewn sides. This is [probably a bug](https://www.blender.community/c/rightclickselect/ZScbbc/), still occurs in v2.92). If you can't get rid of it you can apply the *Cloth* modifier and fill the gap manually in *Edit* mode (select edge, then <kbd>F</kbd>).

One last thing, the head's mesh is very dense. For texturing and animating it's better to keep it as low-poly as possible. You can bake normal maps to add details. I don't know if you're planning to do retopology anyway, and I'm only saying this because you're new to Blender.

Comment: Hello..Thank you so much for helping me out. The clipping option was always on ...Before simulating the clothes.. The mirror modifier seemed like it was working perfectly  fine. But I later noticed when I changed to object mode and  moved the character.. I noticed that the character, eyeball, everything are actually not symmetrical. I mean it kind of is.. But it seems the Gizmo for the character looks like it's rotated and that's messing up the everything ..idk I'm just guessing but  That is why I am so confused why this happened 

Comment: I would really appreciate other solutions if you know my problem! I just remembered that even when I was sculpting my character's face the mirror option didn't work properly. it looked as if the mirror modifier failed calculating where is the face's center. So I had to google for answers and after even relocating the gizmo.....It still seems like it doesn't work :(

Comment: You can upload your file here https://pasteall.org/blend/ if you want. Then we can have a look. Just copy the URL (https://pasteall.org/<IDoflettersandnumbers>....) here after the upload.

Comment: Omg Thanks! I just uploaded the file right now :) thanks so much !!

Comment: Great! But you need to post here the new URL that you got after the upload so we can download it. Check the web address in the browser. It changes.

Comment: Oh ok! This is the new URL ( https://pasteall.org/blend/cb2560158d1046e297598a46ceecc021 ) :)

Comment: OMG Thank you so much for the details and everything  You are truly the best!!!!! Thanks to your help I solved the problem!!! love u sirrrrrrr