rigify not showing the left hand. Edit*(dont know how to change the script to solve the bug) update* (somehow i fixed it)
My regenerate rig's "rig" not showing the left arm
I used the Rigify to rig, I did made the whole bone thing? although its not done like I still need to use the weight painting to "rig?", but when I try to regenerate the rig the left arms not showing. I don't know is it because I used the weight painting and adjust the rig (or maybe I did something wrong), and made the regenerate rig's "rig" not showing the left arm.
I know I have so many problem in my blender but since no one teaches and I cant find the solution I have zero idea of how to solve it.

Its the missing bone problem, yet my small brain cannot process how to change the script
I changed the dest_rig to 'rig' and yet it show this to me:
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tiger\Downloads\robot machine (1).blend\Text", line 23, in <module>
KeyError: 'root'

Update:

final update:
as I say in the title, yes I fixed it...somehow...
firstly, thankyou for teaching me how to solve it, sadly it didn't work maybe I did some oopsy.@blunder
it show this after I did the thing you told me to do:
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\tiger\Downloads\robot machine (1).blend\Text", line 23, in 
KeyError: 'breast.L'
so because i had a backup, this time instead of using "Basic Human (metarig)", i choose the complex? one, the "Human (metarig)".
and it worked.
so i was thinking whats the problem from it.
was the "Basic Human (metarig)" got some bug? or was it because i edited the rig and did something to the weight.
Not sure but this time when i choose to use "Human (metarig)", i only adjust the bone place and delete the face and one finger(my robot only got 4 finger)
after adjusting i just press the generate rig from rigify and it came out normally.
So if someone also got this problem maybe try to use the "Human (metarig)" I guess LOL.
And again huge thanks to @blunder for helping and teaching me. Thankyou.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

the missing arm bones could be a result of a bug. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/108975/107598. You can use the script of the answer (Blender 2.9) to copy your metarig to a new one. The bones should then be present again.

Hi. Your first try was right. You need to add a new metarig (Add > Armature > Rigify Meta-Rigs > ...), and name it metarig.001 for example. Then you have 2 of them, the edited broken one (source_rig='metarig') and the new default one (dest_rigs=['metarig.001']). Now run the script and it will copy your edits. Finally, generate the rig from the new metarig.001 with Rigify's Generate Rig button.

But I think you should fix a few more things before you generate the rig. 1) Your model and the metarig should be at the world origin (0,0,0) and stand on the "floor" (XY-plane). Move them up! 2) You model is turned around by 90° around the Z axis. In front view (numpad 1) it should look at you but you will see the side view. Turn it around. 3) Make sure you apply the rotation, scale and location for the metarig and scale & rotation for the mesh object(s).

Have a look here (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273345/107598) for the 1) issue and for the 2) here (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/227497/107598) and here (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/322180/107598, point 1.2)

Final note, to rig the robot don't use Automatic Weights but assign the weights of the mesh parts manually to the related bone (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/240289/107598). You also can parent a mesh part (e.g arm) to a single bone (Ctrl+P > Bone). But this might not work when you plan to export the model to a game or external program.

@Blunder please use the answer section to answer questions. Comments should be only used to discuss details. They could be removed at any time by the bot and are not referenced as much important.
